# How to extract fractional digits of double/BigDecimal

Tags: java

Say we have a double value of `12345.6789` (should be dynamic)

Now the requirement is split the number and get the decimal digits and fractional digits, which would be:

```
double number = 12345.6789;
int decimal = 12345;
int fractional = 6789;
```

I get the decimal part work out but could you please give a hint on the fractional part? Thanks a lot.

Comment: You need to decide if you're looking for the fractional part of the *printed* representation, or if you're willing to accept the seeming disparity in accuracy in the actual binary representation.

Comment: @seh there is a difference that the fractional should only contain digits without the puncture.

Comment: The only way is to set the number of decimals to work with... Example with 2 decimals: 0.01 would be 1, and 0.10 would be 10. Look at my answer.

Comment: This is not an exact duplicate as here the fraction digits as int are asked.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

```
double number = 12345.6789; // you have this
int decimal = (int) number; // you have 12345
double fractional = number - decimal // you have 0.6789
```

The problem here is that the fractional part is not written in memory as "0.6789", but may have certain "offsets", so to say. For example `0.6789` can be stored as `0.67889999291293929991`.

I think your main concern here isn't **getting** the fractional part, but getting the fractional part with a certain **precision**.

If you'd like to get the exact values you assigned it to, you may want to consider this (altho, it's not a clean solution):

```
String doubleAsText = "12345.6789";
double number = Double.parseDouble(doubleAsText);
int decimal = Integer.parseInt(doubleAsText.split("\.")[0]);
int fractional = Integer.parseInt(doubleAsText.split("\.")[1]);
```

But, as I said, this is not the most efficient and cleanest solution.

Comment: It needs a regex String argument for split method. So you need to use "\\." 

ref: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14833048/2000405

Comment: With your second solution for "exact values", if the fractional part starts with 0's, you will lose those 0's, ending up with a very different number.

Comment: Work fine for `double` but does not work for `Double`.

Answer (score 10):

You can't do what you want to do in an exact way.

One problem is if you have the number `1.05` what should the result be?

```
double number = 1.05;
int decimal = 1;
int fractional = 5; // Oops! "1.05" and "1.5" give the same result.
```

How about this?

```
int fractional = 05; // Still not correct. This is an octal number.
```

Another problem is that the double type can't exactly represent `12345.6789`. It stores a slightly different number instead. This is called representation error. So the fractional part won't actually be `6789`. Instead you can round it off to some number of decimal places.

```
int fractional = (int)Math.round((number - decimal) * 1000);
```

Comment: Won't really work all the time as the fractional part can have more then 4 digits :)

Comment: @Mark Byers thank you for the solution, but what about the fraction part is dynamic so we don't know how long it is so the *1000 solution may not be working. If the double is 12345.678 then it becomes *100.

Comment: @Subarule: I didn't give you a solution, I gave you an explanation of why it can't be done without changing the requirements. Which requirement are you willing to change?

Comment: @Mark Byers May be convert to String and process and get back could be a solution?

Answer (score 3):

You must decide how many decimals to support. I use this method:

```
int decimals = 2;
BigDecimal value = new BigDecimal(123.45).setScale(decimals, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN);
BigInteger INTEGER = value.abs().toBigInteger();
//(value - INTEGER) * (10 ^ decimais)
BigInteger DECIMAL = ((value.subtract(new BigDecimal(INTEGER))).multiply(new BigDecimal(10).pow(decimals))).toBigInteger();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert to `String`, find the decimal point, get the substring and then convert back to Integer.

```
String numberStr = Double.toString(number);
String fractionalStr = numberStr.substring(numberStr.indexOf('.')+1);
int fractional = Integer.valueOf(fractionalStr);
```

Comment: does not work when Double.toString returns scientific exponent notation.